# combine data - keep unique key

Tags: mysql

I have several large tables (~100 million rows in total) which all have a similar schema: They log certain settings of an object (u_id) at a point of time

```
u_id | x | y | time
---------------------------
1    | 2 | 3 | [timestamp]
1    | 1 | 3 | [timestamp]
2    | 1 | 2 | [timestamp]
2    | 2 | 5 | [timestamp]
3    | 3 | 2 | [timestamp]
```

I now want to combine these tables into one large table which is holding ALL data. However I want to leave the u_ids unique. Obviously each source table does have e.g. u_id *1*. When combining the data in the result table the entries should still be distinguishable (however I do not need to associate them back to their original values). This only has to be done once so performance does not matter.

My first idea was to add a prefix (like `a_`, `b_`, etc.) to each u_id before writing it to the destination but this obviously would introduce overhead. I'd prefer that the destination table would use an AI value for minimum overhead but I don't know how to achieve that as each source `u_id` can have multiple (several thousand) entries.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take one column for Type in your destination table . Type will be represent different tables of source . then you can combine u_id and Type as primary key . it will solve your problem .

Comment: Yes, that also came into my mind. But I am talking of 100 million rows here, so this will introduce a relatively large overhead (from a storage point of view - this is relevant as the data will be offered for download). I'd prefer if it would be possible to just create a new AI key.

Comment: auto increment. Lets say source tables a, b and c have several entries for `u_id` *1* than the solution with the smallest overhead would be that in the result table the entries are represented with ids `1`, `2` and `3`